# Access to the path is denied during file move from windows to linux media share

Tags: c#, media, file-permissions

I'm writing a program using C# that renames some files and uploads to my WD MyCloud media share (runs a Linux server). The issue is I keep getting an "Access to the path is denied" when the File.move() is called. The media share is mapped to my network and I'm running as administrator. I have no issues when manually transferring the files, only when I use the File class.

The media share will not allow me to enable all permissions and is giving me a "Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied."

```
try 
{
    File.Move(file.FullName, MEDIA_SHARE_DIR);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

EDIT: Needed to include the directory AND the filename

Comment: Show the code you've written. Also, is this happening all the time or some of the time?

Comment: Yeah, every file transfer is denied access

Comment: Is seasonDir a directory or filename in this context?

Comment: It's the path to the media share accessed via 192.xxx.x.x/videos

Comment: I think it should be the destination filename

Comment: is this shared folder on your local network? have you setup network sharing what is the actual file path vs trying to access it via the IP address..? have you tried Mapping a drive to that location .. ?